# Am I completely misunderstanding how to Equals and/or EqualSequence in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, object

Please take a look at the screenshot. I am comparing two lists of objects that seem to be equal to me. Why are both Equals and EqualSequence false?

[image: Screenshot debugging Equals and EqualSequence of two lists of objects]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and how much understanding you have about the concept. It is also not clear how did you create those two lists? You might want to read more about how Equals and EqualSequence work.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+equals+equalitycomparer

Comment: The `Equals` method is the default for comparing any two objects and it only returns true if the objects are the same object. Two separate instances of a list are not equal even if they contain the exact same objects in the same order.

Comment: It would be nice if you read a bit about how they work and [how the two methods differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511130/difference-between-equals-and-sequenceequal)

Comment: The `SequenceEqual` (not `EqualSequence` as you've put it) checks if the elements of both sequences are equal by pairing up each value in the sequence. Each comparison of each element uses the default `Equals` - so without overriding `Equals` you are comparing the reference and not the content of each element. The lists also need to be the same length.

Comment: If you post your code that you have already tried it would be easier to point you in the right direction. At the current point in time, without any other context, the only real answer to the title you have is: Yes.

Comment: There's no way, I can read that small text in your image, post it as text instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `Equals` method is the default for comparing any two objects and it only returns true if the objects are the same object. Two separate instances of a list are not equal even if they contain the exact same objects in the same order.

The `SequenceEqual` (not `EqualSequence` as you've put it) checks if the elements of both sequences are equal by pairing up each value in the sequence. Each comparison of each element uses the default `Equals` - so without overriding `Equals` you are comparing the reference and not the content of each element. The lists also need to be the same length.

Let's check this. Start with this code:

```
public class BusinessProductCategory
{
    public int ProductID;
    public int CategoryID;
}

List<BusinessProductCategory> _incoming = new List<BusinessProductCategory>()
{
    new BusinessProductCategory() { CategoryID = 1, ProductID = 2},
    new BusinessProductCategory() { CategoryID = 3, ProductID = 4},
};

List<BusinessProductCategory> _existing = new List<BusinessProductCategory>()
{
    new BusinessProductCategory() { CategoryID = 1, ProductID = 2},
    new BusinessProductCategory() { CategoryID = 3, ProductID = 4},
};
```

Those are clearly equal. Let's try `SequenceEqual`.

```
Console.WriteLine(_incoming.SequenceEqual(_existing));
```

That outputs `false` because the instances are not the same.

Now I create an `IEqualityComparer<BusinessProductCategory>` class like this:

```
public class BusinessProductCategoryEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<BusinessProductCategory>
{
    public bool Equals(BusinessProductCategory x, BusinessProductCategory y) =>
        x.CategoryID.Equals(y.CategoryID) && x.ProductID.Equals(y.ProductID);
        
    public int GetHashCode(BusinessProductCategory obj) =>
        obj.CategoryID.GetHashCode() ^ obj.ProductID.GetHashCode();
}
```

Now when I run this:

```
Console.WriteLine(_incoming.SequenceEqual(_existing, new BusinessProductCategoryEqualityComparer()));
```

I get `true`.

Had I done this, though:

```
_incoming = _existing.ToList();

Console.WriteLine(_incoming.SequenceEqual(_existing));
```

I would also get `true` as I'm comparing the same instances of each object.

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to implement an `IEqualityComparer<BusinessProductCategory>` class, then you must make your `BusinessProductCategory` class read-only and override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods like so:

```
public class BusinessProductCategory
{
    public int ProductID { get; init; }
    public int CategoryID { get; init; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        obj is BusinessProductCategory @that
        && this.CategoryID.Equals(@that.CategoryID)
        && this.ProductID.Equals(@that.ProductID);

    public override int GetHashCode() =>
        this.CategoryID.GetHashCode()
        ^ this.ProductID.GetHashCode();
}
```

Now with this version of the class then the following line returns `true`:

```
Console.WriteLine(_incoming.SequenceEqual(_existing));
```